# Plotting a grouped bar graph from csv in R

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hello I have this data frame and I would like to draw the bar graph for the number of positive and negative across each year. I wish to have one bar that represents the number of positive and the other that represents the number of negative for each year.

[image]

Comment: can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: `[your code] %>% ggplot(aes(year, n, color = comment_emotion)) + geom_col()`.  If you look at the help for `?geom_col` you'll see there are options for `position = "dodge"` or `position = "stack"` or `position = "fill"` for different ways of arranging the two bars.